# SqlAlchemy: proper way to do a bare exists query

Tags: sqlalchemy, exists, turbogears

I've the following construct which seems to produce the desired SQL:

```
>>> print session.query(exists('1').where(MyTable.name=='x'))
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.name = :name_1) AS anon_1
```

However, when I try to execute it with `.scalar()` or `.all()` it returns the error:

`*** UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session`

How can I bind it for this simple query?  I don't want to do `bool(MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.name=='x').first())` as that wastefully pulls back the entire row from the table.

---

Update:

I've also tried:

```
>>> session.connection(mapper=MyTable).execute(
        exists('1').where(MyTable.name=='x'))
StatementError: Not an executable clause 'EXISTS \
  (SELECT 1 \nFROM my_table \nWHERE my_table.name = %(name_1)s)' []
```

Comment: You should have a line that reads `session.configure(bind=engine)`

Comment: `session.configure()` throws error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'configure'`   
`session.__class__` is `sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession`

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Please add the relevant code where `session` is constructed and where `session.configure()` is run.

Comment: Hmmm I'm using TurboGears (1.5.1), investigating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it I think:

```
>>> session.connection(mapper=MyTable).execute(
      select([exists('1').where(MyTable.name=='x')]))
```